# Parse "cannot sign up without username"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I made a user sign up system with parse, but it keeps saying "cannot signup without username" even if there is a string passed to PFUser's username property. What causes this error?

```
            let user = PFUser() 
            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool,error:NSError?)-> Void in if error==nil{
                user.username = self.username.text!
                user.password=self.Password.text!
                user.email=self.Email.text!
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UploadImageViewController(),animated:true)
                }
            else {let errorMessage: String = error!.userInfo["error"] as! String;self.displayErrorMessage(errorMessage)}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually assign those properties before you call `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock`

Something like this:

```
let user = PFUser() 
user.username = self.username.text!
user.password=self.Password.text!
user.email=self.Email.text!

user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
(succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if let error = error {
let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString
// Handle the error
} else {
// Push your view controller
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to set those properties before trying to sign up the user.

```
let user = PFUser()
user.password = password.text
user.username = username.text
//add other properties you might want
user.signUpInBackgroudWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> in 
    if success && error == nil {
        //success
    } else {
        //error
    }
```